# Future Task rejected from ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I have a `ThreadPoolExecutor` and I submit a task to it.

```
private ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1));
```

This code submits the `Runnable` to the `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

```
 protected void waitAndSweep(final String symbol) {

    runnable = new Runnable() {
      public void run() { /* irrelevant code */ }
    };

    try {
      Future<?> self = threadPoolExecutor.submit(runnable);
      futures.add(self);
    } catch (RejectedExecutionException re) {
      /* this exception will be thrown when wait and sweep is called more than twice.
       * threadPoolExecutor can have one running task and one waiting task.
       */
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logEvent(StrategyEntry.ERROR, "waitAndSweep", symbol, "Exception caught...", e);
    }
  }
```

The following code stops the task.

```
protected synchronized void stop(StrategyEntry entry) throws Exception {
    for (Object future : futures) {
      ((Future<?>) future).cancel(true);
    }
    futures.clear();

    threadPoolExecutor.shutdown();
}
```

The problem here is: When I try to stop the task, I am getting following exception:

> Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@3a475611 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@216393fb[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]

Comment: Do you call `shutdown()` on this executor anywhere?

Comment: You are creating a backing queue with capacity 1 - is there some other task already in there?

Comment: @AndyTurner From the error he gets it is clearly visible that the executor is in the `Terminated` state - that what is causing the exception.

Comment: If some other task already in there, executor will reject the task and it will be caught by catch block and it will be never displayed in the GUI.

Comment: What line in your code throws the exception? What is the type of the exception?

Comment: @MMPgm Did you ever manage to get an answer to this question

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that you `shutdown()` the excutor in the stop method. If you just want to wait for the task to complete, use `Future.get()`. When a executor is shut down, tasks can no longer be submitted to it.

`shutdown()` should only be used when you actually want to terminate the application.

Comment: When executor is shutdown, I do not want any new task to be submitted

Comment: @MMPgm From your question, it is not entirely clear what you expect the `stop()` method to actually do. Maybe you can clarify that?

Comment: Stop method should kill all waiting task and it should not accept any other task. I just wanted to know what is the possible case for the exception to occur.